# Prevent <label></label> from resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV element which has a `<label></label>` and input textbox inside it.

Basically, I have enabled jQuery .resizable() on the DIV element but when you make the DIV element smaller than it currently is, the textbox is pushed onto a new line.

How can I force the `<label>` to never go smaller than a set size?

Thanks!

```
<div id='div1' style='width:300px'>
    <label>Test&nbsp;
        <input type='text' style='width:100px' id='inputBox'/>
    </label>
</div>

$("#div1").resizable({
    handles: "e, w, sw, ne, nw, se"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Give it a `min-width`:

```
<div id='div1' style='width: 300px; min-width: 300px;'>
```

Or, preferably:

```css
#div1 {
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI's resizable has a minWidth property ([example from the docs](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#max-min)):

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      maxHeight: 250,
      maxWidth: 350,
      minHeight: 150,
      minWidth: 200
});
```

So you could set the maxWidthProperty to `$("label").width()`.